# Scraping same class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape stats from https://www.flashscore.com/match/OxfWpyjH/#match-summary/match-statistics/0
I tried this code for the first row Ball Possession

```
_bp = soup.find('div', text='Ball Possession')
_hp = _bp.find('div', class_=re.compile('homeValue')).text
_ap = _ap.find('div', class_=re.compile('awayValue')).text
```

Here how looks like [image]

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Post edited, the question is how to scrape ball possession for home and away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luca,

You can use the below **code** :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/match/OxfWpyjH/#match-summary/match-statistics/0")
ball_Possession_left_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Ball Possession']/preceding-sibling::div"))).text
ball_Possession_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Ball Possession']"))).text
ball_Possession_right_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Ball Possession']/following-sibling::div"))).text
print(ball_Possession_left_value, ball_Possession_value, ball_Possession_right_value)
```

You can use the below code to extract every stat from the web page :

```
all_category = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='categoryName']")
all_homeValue = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='homeValue']")
all_awayValue = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='awayValue']")

max_count = len(all_category)
print(max_count)
count = 0
while count < max_count:
    print(all_homeValue[count].text, all_category[count].text, all_awayValue[count].text)
    count = count + 1
```